# Wrap whole lines of uppercase text in bbcode bold tags

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a regular expression for detecting and **wrapping uppercase** lines with *[b]..[/b]*.

I have a description. This description varies, as it describes games and not all descriptions have a line consisting of only uppercase words.

How can I return a a string that has lines containing only uppercase words and wrap with those tags?

**Example**

> BUILD THE ULTIMATE BRAWLER
>
> Design your ultimate LEGO Minifigure hero with unique style, strategy
> and personality. A cactus with an attitude? A scrappy janitor ninja
> who happens to have fighting chickens? A sledgehammer-swinging clown
> with a few scores to settle? Sure! Build the ultimate brawler and
> level them up with unlockable content!
>
> BATTLE THROUGH EPIC LEGO THEMES
>
> From the swashbuckling shores of Barracuda Bay, to the waterlogged
> caverns of Ninjago® Seabound, to a dusty wild west saloon and the
> mythical Monkie Kid jungle, all of your favorite LEGO themes are
> brawlable! Collect unlockable minifigs, power-ups, and emotes along
> the way.
>
> CROSS-PLAY WITH FRIENDS ACROSS PLATFORMS
>
> Team up and brawl 4v4, party with friends, or play a battle
> royale-style game mode where it’s “every-player-for-themself”. With
> multiple game modes, levels have unique challenges and win conditions.

I want to return ALL of that, but with the **detected uppercase lines** each wrapped with [b] [/b].

My attempted pattern:

```
/([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)+)\n/mg
```

https://regex101.com/r/GBLVLU/1

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `preg_replace()` here:

```php
$input = "BUILD THE ULTIMATE BRAWLER\n\nDesign your ultimate LEGO Minifigure hero with unique style, strategy and personality. A cactus with an attitude? A scrappy janitor ninja who happens to have fighting chickens? A sledgehammer-swinging clown with a few scores to settle? Sure! Build the ultimate brawler and level them up with unlockable content!";
$output = preg_replace("/([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)+)\n/", "[b]$1[/b]\n", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

> [b]BUILD THE ULTIMATE BRAWLER[/b]

> Design your ultimate LEGO Minifigure hero with unique style, strategy and personality. A cactus with an attitude? A scrappy janitor ninja who happens to have fighting chickens? A sledgehammer-swinging clown with a few scores to settle? Sure! Build the ultimate brawler and level them up with unlockable content!

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with the `m` flag, but that flag has no meaning to a pattern with no anchors (`^`, `$`).

Using start of line and end of line anchors around a character class that contains only uppercase letters and spaces and hyphens.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Oh41m))

```
echo preg_replace('/^[A-Z -]+$/m', '[b]$0[/b]', $text);
```

If your text may contain multibyte characters (such as accented characters), then add `u` after the `m` pattern modifier.

---

Alternatively, if you want to apply bold bbcode tags to full lines that do not contain any lowercase letters, then the following pattern uses a negated character class to match one or more characters on a single line that do not contain a lowercase letter ([`\p{Ll}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#:%7E:text=a%20lowercase%20letter%20that%20has%20an%20uppercase%20variant.)) and no "vertical whitespaces".  This is unicode/multibyte safe.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NboHI))

```
echo preg_replace('/^[^\p{Ll}\v]+$/mu', '[b]$0[/b]', $text);
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I get the original text returned with [?] chars

Comment: I've extended my answer to accommodate unicode characters.

Comment: The expression works, but it does not work when applied to PHP. Only this (mostly) works. Can you update to work with your expression?
```preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)+)/', function($matches) { return "[b]{$matches[0]}[/b]"; }, $string);```

Comment: My answer 100% works with PHP as proven by 2 different PHP demos.  Please provide the sample input that my answer fails to accommodate.  Please create a 3v4l.org demo link to show me how my code breaks with your REAL input text.  Using `preg_replace_callback()` is not necessary at all.

Comment: Im realizing I dont need replace callback too, it seems completely redundant now. I ended up with https://regex101.com/r/x8J2Uv/1 which does the job nicely. Thanks I'll update the code!

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you cooperated with the support that I am trying to offer you.  I am giving you professional advice, but you seem to be going your own way instead.

Comment: That is smart with the `\v` in the character class. I think if you also don't want to match lines with spaces only `^\h*[^\p{Ll}\s][^\p{Ll}\v]*$`

Comment: Good point.  I didn't consider the possibility of lines consisting of only horizontal whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

The following matches all uppercase lines, wraps lines with bbcode and returns text

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z-]+(?: [A-Z]+)+)(\r\n|\r|\n)/', function($matches) { 
   return "[b]{$matches[0]}[/b]"; 
}, $string);
```

Comment: This answer is not correct/suitable/appropriate because it does not match full lines (only trailing text before a linebreak). Proof: https://3v4l.org/YNdHC  `preg_replace_callback()` offers no advantage over `preg_replace()` for the task requirements.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in my use case and handles breaks without modifications. Works on PHP 5.3+

Comment: And will work identically to this simpler code: `echo preg_replace('/([A-Z-]+(?: [A-Z]+)+)\R/', "[b]$0[/b]", $string);` ... but I believe that the pattern is suboptimal/incorrect because it doesn't handle fringe cases.  It contains no start or end of line anchors, does not accomodate hyphens or commas in heading text, and includes newlines in the tag wrapped text.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer.  It works for your sample data.  If it does not work for your application text, then your question is Unclear and will need to be edited or closed.